# Can you use TFS API with only query strings? Trying to queue build from Slack

Tags: tfs, slack

Using On-Premise TFS 2017 and Slack.  Just trying to find a way for people to manually queue builds.  Slack Slash Commands will *almost* work, but can't seem to send JSON bodies, so I'm trying to find out how to send credentials and definition IDs using only query strings...

Some background:

- Our people cannot run unsigned Powershell Scripts because of Group Policy overrides for ExecutionPolicy.
- Don't want to give people access to queue builds through web interface.
- We are using CI/CD, but need to manually queue for QA/Demo builds.
- Wanted to avoid using another app as a go-between if possible, since new environments for hosting are hard to come by here.

Is there a way to hit the TFS API through Slack Slash Commands?

Comment: Don't think it's possible :/ you must send the request body.